# Perl Help Needed: Replacing values

Tags: perl

I am having an input file like this:

[Input file](http://pastebin.com/Ch04j38h)

I need to replace the value `@pSBSB_ID="*"` of `@rectype=@pRECTYPE="SBSB"` with `@pMEME_SSN="034184233"`, value of `@pRECTYPE="SMSR"`, ..and have to delete the row where `@rectype='@pRECTYPE="SMSR",` '

Example:
So, after changes have been made, the file should be like this:

```
....@pRECTYPE="SBSB", @pGWID="17199269", @pINPUT_METHOD="E", @pGS08="005010X220A1",    @pSBSB_FAM_UPDATE_CD="UP", @pSBSB_ID="034184233".....
....@pRECTYPE="SBEL", @pSBEL_EFF_DT="01/01/2013", @pSBEL_UPDATE_CD="TM", @pCSPD_CAT="M", @pCSPI_ID="MHMO1003"
.
.
.
```

*Update*

I tried below mentioned code:
Input file extension: mms and there are multiple files to process.

```
my $save_for_later;
my $record;
my @KwdFiles;
my $r;
my $FilePath = $ARGV[0];

chdir($FilePath);

@KwdFiles = <*>;
foreach $File(@KwdFiles)
{
    unless(substr($File,length($File)-4,length($File)) eq '.mms')
        {
            next;
        }
    unless(open(INFILE, "$File"))
        {
            print "Unable to open file: $File";
            exit(0);
        }
    print  "Successfully opened the file: \"$File\" for processing\n\n";
    while ( my $record = <INFILE> ) {
    my %r = $record =~ /\@(\w+) = '(.*?)'/xg;

    if ($r{rectype} eq "SMSR") {
    $save_for_later = $r{pMEME_SSN};
    next;
    }
    elsif ($r{rectype} eq "SBSB" and $r{pSBSB_ID} eq "*") {
  $record =~ s|(\@pSBSB_ID = )'.*?'|$1'$save_for_later'|x;
    }

close(INFILE);
```

}
}

But, I am still not getting the updated values in the file.

Comment: It looks like you copied the `@rec_id` from the deleted `ABC` line above twice. Was that intentional, or a typo? You should be exceedingly careful when posting sample input and output and when explaining what you need done.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open IN, "< in.txt";
open OUT, "> out.txt";
my $CUR_RECID = 1^1;
while (<IN>) {
  if ($CUR_RECID) {
    s/recname='.+?'/recname='$CUR_RECID'/ if /rectype='DEF'/;
    $CUR_RECID = 1^1;
    print OUT;
  }
  $CUR_RECID = $1 if /rectype='ABC'.+?rec_id='(.+?)'/;
}
close OUT;
close IN;
```

Try that whole code. No need a separate function; This code does everything.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`. Use three argument `open()` with a lexical file handle. And always check the return value of `open`, with e.g. `or die $!`. Also, what is `1^1` supposed to achieve?

Comment: @TLP Thank you for your input. I'm not a newbie in Perl; I just had to give a fast reply to this question; I 'm not pretending to propose here a perfectly acceptable Perl program. IMHO, we'd let the person who asked  the question add other cosmetics. This code does the job and produces the result we want. That's all. It give main guidelines. I do not teach Perl here, unless the question asks to ;)

Comment: Well, that's the beauty of this site: You can edit your answers to change their content. And you are wrong, we are here to teach Perl, that is the purpose of this site. The purpose is not to provide free code, but to provide learning.

Comment: @TLP I do think that the purpose of this site is to give very specific answers to very specific questions, nothing else. For teaching, you have sites like Khan Academy (https://www.khanacademy.org/).

Comment: Well, is wikipedia's purpose to provide answers, or to educate? And also, an "answer" is not just about providing the finished product, but about explaining how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script from your terminal with the files to be modified as arguments:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; #modify original file and create a backup of the old ones with .bak appended to the name

my $replacement; 

while (<>) {
    $replacement = $1 if m/(?<=\@pMEME_SSN=)("\d+")/; #assume replacement will be on the first line of every file.
    next if m/^\s*\@pRECTYPE="SMSR"/;
    s/(?<=\@pSBSB_ID=)("\*")/$replacement/g; 
    print;
}
```